# Get selected table row and use function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

Here I have a datatable: http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/15/edit

I add data to table and show it. After that I add new column - kontrole.

```
data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Donuts eaten'],
        ['Michael' , 'Male', 12, 5],
        ['Elisa', 'Female', 20, 7],
        ['Robert', 'Male', 7, 3],
        ['John', 'Male', 54, 2],
        ['Jessica', 'Female', 22, 6],
        ['Aaron', 'Male', 3, 1],
        ['Margareth', 'Female', 42, 8],
        ['Miranda', 'Female', 33, 6]
    ]);

    data.insertRows(0, [['Drew', 'Male', 32, 1]]);

          data.addColumn('string', 'Kontrole');
         for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
    if (data.getValue(y, 4) != 'a') {
      data.setValue(y, 4, '<button id="edit" class="btn btn-info">edit row</button>');
    }
}
```

In new empty rows I add html button: `<button id="edit" class="btn btn-info">edit row</button>`

Now I want to when I click on button ID edit to call this code:

```
new google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.addListener(table.getChart(), 'select', function () {
            var selection = table.getChart().getSelection();
            // iterate over all selected rows
            for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
              $("#edit").removeClass("btn btn-success disabled")
              $('#edit').addClass('btn btn-success');
              $("#name").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,0));
              $("#gender").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,1));
              $("#age").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,2));
              $("#donuts_eaten").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(selection[i].row,3));

            }
        });
    });
```

When I have separated button (outside table) this code works great, but when I put button ID =edit into table then won't to work?

What can be problem here?

Comment: Here you can see: http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/16 button ID=edit work outside table but dont work into table row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a `select` event handler for the Table cancels event bubbling on the table, so the click is never registered on your edit buttons (your code would actually fire an edit when the user clicks anywhere in a row).  If you want to use a click event handler for your buttons, this is the way to do it.  First, you need to fix the way you are creating buttons (as you cannot have multiple elements with the same ID, and you need to be able to identify which row the button belongs to:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Kontrole');
for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
    if (data.getValue(y, 4) == null) {
        data.setValue(y, 4, '<button class="edit btn btn-info" data-row="' + y + '">edit row</button>');
    }
}
```

Then, instead of using the table's `select` event handler, use a `click` event handler for the buttons:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function () {
    var row = parseInt($(this).data('row'));
    $(this).removeClass("btn btn-success disabled")
    $(this).addClass('btn btn-success');
    $("#name").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(row,0));
    $("#gender").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(row,1));
    $("#age").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(row,2));
    $("#donuts_eaten").val(table.getDataTable().getValue(row,3));
});
```

Comment: but dont work: CODE: http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/18/edit , DEMO: http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/18/edit I update my code with your

Comment: Don't use the google event handlers at all - the jQuery I posted in my answer is a replacement of the google event handlers.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with google handler becouse i need it in some other development option that I need to add... I create here something http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/20v but work only for 1st. row.

Comment: also when I implement your code i cant open modal window and cant see input fields ...

Comment: I solve my problem with google events; http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/20 please look... also thanks for helping